# Modelica: Which algorithm for which model? Dassl, Euler

Tags: algorithm, modelica, dymola, openmodelica

OpenModelica or Dymola provide several algorithms to simulate a model: Dassl, Euler, Rungekutta, inline-rungekutta, Radau...

How choose the right one?